# iOS Host public url

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Lets say I have a pdf file on an iOS device that I want to transmit wirelessly to another iOS device.
Is there a way to simply get an NSURL from the file on device A so that device B can directly access it?

I'd like to skip the step of having to post it to a server first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible by making device A into an *ad hoc* HTTP server. You can find implementation help here:

http://code.google.com/p/cocoahttpserver/

It works quite well, but needs some fiddling.

Comment: This is amazing! Do you know if it supports HTTP live streaming?

Comment: I did not try this. But theoretically it might work. Please let me know if you try it.

Comment: I tested it out with Mat Gallagher's AudioStream http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/revisiting-old-post-streaming-and.html
And it works beautifully!